# How do I make Roles.ApplicationName threadsafe?

Tags: asp.net, membership, roles, roleprovider

I am currently writing a user management application which administers users in a single aspnetdb instance. This single instance contains multiple "applications" which all have roles assigned against the individual applications.

As each user can be a member of multiple applications I use `Roles.ApplicationName` to cycle through each configured application and then determine which roles they are a member of. After checking each application I set the `Roles.ApplicationName` back to the original application which is the management application.

The problem I am having is when multiple users eachview an individual application and a request for `Roles.GetAllRoles()` is made. Most of the time the roles that come back are for the intended application but sometimes the wrong application's roles come back due to other requests cycling over the `Roles.ApplicationName` per application.

I've since read that `Roles.ApplicationName` is not threadsafe and therefore should not be used in a web application but I would prefer to have a solution to this rather than having to rewrite the role model in the application.

Also, The aspnetdb applications are created via this administration system and therefore I cannot create multiple RoleProviders, one per application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you write a wrapper to do this, off the top of my head you could implement your own role provider, and then put the appropriate synchronization in place.

Comment: I done exactly this by wrapping the SqlRoleProvider and creating locks on the methods. This still seemed to lead to problem. However when I wrapped the basic RoleProvider object and made the calls to the appropriate aspnetdb sps manually everything was fine.